# Bxslider variable / incremental width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

I'm trying to make a slider (using `bxSlider`) similar to [this one](http://www.31philliplim.com/collections/womens-pf12-ready-to-wear).

It seems the `div` containing the slider changes its width in equal increments depending on the width of the user's browser.  In other words, the `div` never cuts off the image partially, it always shows the full picture or hides it.

Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/)

For that you have to know how wide your images are, so you can calculate the width of the slider container.

Just a quick example - your images are 200px wide. So for screens between 800 and 1000px your image container has to be `800px` - only 4 images can fit without crop. For screens between 1000 and 1200px - `1000px`, so 5 images fit, etc.